# Timezone conversion for a specific datetime in java

Tags: java, timezone

I will be giving input date time for a timezone and the timezone for the input date time and we want the relevant DateTime in the expected timezone.

And here is my method.

```
convertToTimezone("03/08/2010 20:19:00 PM","Asia/Shanghai","US/Central");
```

The above time is the time in Asia/Shanghai. We would like to know what is the corresponding time in US/Central.

It's working fine but I am getting a 1-hour difference from the actual time.

Can I know where I am going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateUtil {

    private static String format_date = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a";

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {
            String sourceTimezone = "Asia/Shanghai";
            String destTimezone = "US/Central";
            String outputExpectedTimezone = convertToTimezone("03/08/2010 20:19:00 PM", sourceTimezone, destTimezone);
            System.out.println("outputExpectedTimezone :" + outputExpectedTimezone);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String convertToTimezone(String inputDate, String inputDateTimezone, String destinationDateTimezone)
            throws Exception {
        String outputDate = null;

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(format_date);
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(inputDateTimezone));

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(inputDateTimezone));
        calendar.setTime(format.parse(inputDate));
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -(calendar.getTimeZone().getRawOffset()));
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -calendar.getTimeZone().getDSTSavings());
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, TimeZone.getTimeZone(destinationDateTimezone).getRawOffset());

        outputDate = format.format(calendar.getTime());
        return outputDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be adding anything to the calendar - that represents a specific instant in time. In fact, you don't need a calendar at all.

Instead, have two different *formats*, one for each time zone:

```
public static String convertToTimezone(String inputDate,
     String inputDateTimezone,
     String destinationDateTimezone)
     throws Exception
{
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(format_date);
    parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(inputDateTimezone));

    Date date = parser.parse(inputDate);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format_date);
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(outputDateTimezone));
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

As an aside, I'd *thoroughly* recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in date/time API.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

- Since your input Date-Time does not have timezone information, parse it into a `LocalDateTime`

  - Attach the timezone of the input Date-Time with it to get a `ZonedDateTime`

    - Use the [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) to convert this `ZonedDateTime` to the target `ZonedDateTime`

      - Return the formatted target `ZonedDateTime`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(convertToTimezone("03/08/2010 20:19:00 PM", "Asia/Shanghai", "US/Central"));
        System.out.println(convertToTimezone("03/08/2010 20:19:00 PM", "Asia/Shanghai", "America/Mexico_City"));
    }

    static String convertToTimezone(String inputDate, String inputDateTimezone, String destinationDateTimezone) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(inputDate, dtf);
        ZonedDateTime zdtInput = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of(inputDateTimezone));
        ZonedDateTime zdtDestination = zdtInput.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(destinationDateTimezone));
        return zdtDestination.format(dtf);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
03/08/2010 06:19:00 AM
03/08/2010 06:19:00 AM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3w7egf)

**Note:** Avoid using the deprecated ID, `US/Central`. Use the standard ID, `America/Mexico_City` where [Mexico City is the largest city in this timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>